# Vuetify - v-autocomplete - search hides the headers

Tags: vuetify.js

Please see the below screenshots where v-autocomplete displays the Header part initially, but when I start searching it is hiding the Header part. Because of this for any remote data, it never displays the headers. Is there any way e can keep the headers and display the results? Thank You.

Here is the code pen example for it

https://codepen.io/kiranvasi/pen/vYBbgEY?&editable=true&editors=101

[image]

[image]

```
 <v-autocomplete
                v-model="friends"
                :disabled="isUpdating"
                :items="people"
                filled
                chips
                color="blue-grey lighten-2"
                label="Select"
                item-text="name"
                item-value="name"
                multiple
              >
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same problem?

Comment: @MaikenMadsen - I am sorry no luck yet :(  I will let you know in case if I find any also in case if you find any please post it here . Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: try adding `no-filter` property to v-autocomplete component. If your `items` is changing dynamically (e.g. `items` is changed after requests to server), additional filtering may break headers and dividers. [image: Vuetify docs]

Comment: Wow great :)  I missed this option .  Thank you for pointing out the option in documentation .

Comment: Also need to remove `cache-items` props if applied

Answer (score 3):

To keep the headers in the displayed results you can modify the function that filters the items to include headers.

`v-autocomplete` has a `filter` prop which accepts a function that determines if an item meets the text typed into the autocomplete which is defined in the source code [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.ts#L40) and shown below

```js
    filter: {
      type: Function,
      default: (item, queryText, itemText) => {
        return itemText.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
      }
```

you can create your own filter method and bind it to the `:filter` prop of the autocomplete. In Vuetify a `v-autocomplete` is an extension of a `v-select` - headers are defined as items which have a `header` property so you could write a filter function like

```js
methods: {
  returnHeadersAndFilter(item, queryText, itemText) {
    if(item.header) {
      return true
    }
    return itemText.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1
  }

}
```

then bind this custom filter method to the filter prop of the v-autocomplete, using your v-autocomplete html

```html
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="friends"
  :disabled="isUpdating"
  :items="people"
  :filter="returnHeadersAndFilter"
  filled
  chips
  color="blue-grey lighten-2"
  label="Select"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="name"
multiple
></v-autocomplete>
```